# Exporting Automation Anywhere commands or editing them in Notepad

Tags: automationanywhere

Is there an easier way to edit Automation Anywhere scripts such as with Notepad and paste them back into AA? For sharing scripts with team members, is there a way to extract the commands into a text file? I can only see a . ATMX file, which seems to be a zip file, but has some commands file, which is encrypted. Is anybody aware of this?

Regards,
Ganesh.

I tried unzipping the ATMX file, which gave an XML and some text files, but all data seems encrypted in it. There is no way to read the commands in it.